# How to identify which MAC address is a WIFI MAC address, and which IP is a WIFI IP Address?

Tags: c, windows

I have the following the functions:

This function will get every IP Addresses from the local machine

```
void GetIP()
{
WORD wVersionRequested;
WSADATA wsaData;
char name[ 255 ];
PHOSTENT hostinfo;
wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD( 1, 1 );
char *ip;

if ( WSAStartup( wVersionRequested, &wsaData ) == 0 )
{
    if( gethostname ( name, sizeof( name ) ) == 0 )
    {
        if ( ( hostinfo = gethostbyname( name ) ) != NULL )
        {
            int nCount = 0;
            while ( hostinfo->h_addr_list[ nCount ] )
            {
                ip = inet_ntoa( *(struct in_addr *)hostinfo->h_addr_list[ nCount ] );

                //printf( "IP #%d: %s\n", ++nCount, ip );
                printf( "IP                 : %s\n", ip );
                ++nCount;
            }
        }
    }
}
}//GetIP
```

And here is my second function, which will get every MAC Address from the local machine:

```
void GetMACaddress()
{
IP_ADAPTER_INFO AdapterInfo[ 16 ];              // Allocate information for up to 16 NICs
DWORD dwBufLen = sizeof( AdapterInfo );         // Save the memory size of buffer

DWORD dwStatus = GetAdaptersInfo(               // Call GetAdapterInfo
                                        AdapterInfo,// [out] buffer to receive data
                                        &dwBufLen   // [in] size of receive data buffer
                                    );  

    assert( dwStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS );            // Verify return value is valid, no buffer overflow

    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo = AdapterInfo;    // Contains pointer to current adapter info

    do 
    {
        printf( "MAC                : %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n", pAdapterInfo->Address[ 0 ], 
                                                                    pAdapterInfo->Address[ 1 ], 
                                                                    pAdapterInfo->Address[ 2 ], 
                                                                    pAdapterInfo->Address[ 3 ], 
                                                                    pAdapterInfo->Address[ 4 ], 
                                                                    pAdapterInfo->Address[ 5 ]  );
                    pAdapterInfo = pAdapterInfo->Next;          // Progress through linked list

    }while( pAdapterInfo );                         // Terminate if last adapter
}//GetMACaddress
```

So my question is:
How do i know if the queried MAC Address and the queried IP Address belongs to a WiFi?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code you have for querying MAC addresses, also fetches the interface type.

Starting with Vista, [for a WiFi interface, the `Type` field will be `IF_TYPE_IEEE80211`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366062)  You can also identify dial-up (`MIB_IF_TYPE_PPP`) connections and loopback (`MIB_IF_TYPE_LOOPBACK`) virtual interfaces.

As [Remy says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449657/how-to-identify-which-mac-address-is-a-wifi-mac-address-and-which-ip-is-a-wifi-i/7449790#7449790), you should pull the IP addresses out of that same data structure (there's an `IpAddressList` field).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetAdaptersInfo()`and `GetAdaptersAddresses()` to get the IPs as well as MACs. I recently discovered that, although commonly used (even my me), using `gethostname()` and `gethostbyname()` can return misleading data at times since `gethostbyname()` is a DNS lookup and can return addresses that are not actually local if the hostname has additional DNS entries configured (load balancing, etc). `GetAdaptersInfo()` and `GetAdaptersAddresses()` only return local settings instead.

In any case, the APIs do not expose info about whether a network adapter is LAN, WAN, WiFi, etc. The OS doesn't really need that info, and neither should you. All it cares about is that a given adapter provides access to a given network. How it does that is a private implementation detail and device-specific. You can interchangeably use adapters without worrying about what types they are.

Comment: Good point about not using `gethostbyname` for listing local IPs, but your conclusion is wrong.

Comment: "In any case, the APIs do not expose info about whether a network adapter is LAN, WAN, WiFi, etc." -- that's just wrong.